# how to make scroll in ionic webpage

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, swipe, infinite-scroll

I am making an android mobile app in ionic framework using angular java script, in which I have to keep upper half of the screen static, while in lower part I need some functionality like sliding pages. Means when I will slide only lower part need to be swipe. Also also by up/down scrolling upper part should be fixed and lower part need to be scroll. I tried using `<ion-slide>` tag for sliding and included bootstrap and jquery libraries in my page for proper mobile view and scrolling, but scroll part is not working, also background image included in upper half of the page is not adjusting its size automatically. Can anyone help me on that?

Thanks...

Comment: Please add code what have you tried.

Comment: sorry, but i am working in an organization and if share my code it may lead to revealing confidential data.

Comment: you have to at least write demo code where you have problem.

Answer (score -1):

try with this way

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webRootOperations"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```